# I am sending id like this <a href="update.html?id="+element.id+> and I want to catch this id in variable on update.html in electron javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to catch this 'id' on "update.html" file in variable which I could use. I am using "electron".

```
a.href = "user.js?id ="+ element.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function getparams(url) {
        var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);
        var id = queryString.split('=')[1];
    }
    getparams();
</script>
```